# Time constant in an RC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, time-constant

[image: RC circuit]

Is it possible for this circuit to have two different time constants? One from 0 to 30µs and the other one from 30µs. I tried to calculate the values and I get τ<sub>1</sub>=20µs and τ2=95/7 µs. They seem quite different so I want someone to confirm or tell me the right way to calculate them.

This is how I did it:

- for t=0: S1 in A is closed while in B is open. S2 is open. I tried to find an equivalent circuit formed of a capacitor, a resistance and a voltage source. I got R=10 ohm, C=2µF, V=20V. So τ<sub>1</sub> = RC = 10*2µF = 20µs
- For t>=30µs: S1 in B is closed and in A is open. S2 is closed. This means that there is no connection between the voltage source and the capacitor. I tried to find an equivalent circuit and I got: R=95/14 ohm, C=2µF V=0V. So τ<sub>2</sub> = 95/7 µs.

Now, let's say I already have the capacitor voltage in a period of time (0 - 100µs). How do I calculate the output voltage (Vout(t))? I get two different expressions again...

Comment: You certainly can have two different time constants. To determine them, you need to reduce the stimulus to 0 V: put S1 in B and determine the resistance "seen" from the capacitor in this configuration. This resistance multiplied by C1 is your time constant. Repeat the exercise when S2 is closed and you have your second time constant. In a 1st-order circuit, the pole is the inverse of the time constant. From the configuration, I can see there is also a zero in the transfer function that you must determine. You have two transfer functions whether S2 is open or closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers are correct.

Note that you should always number your components in a schematic (e.g. R1, R2, C1, etc). It would make describing this circuit a less ambiguous task.

The time constants in the following description refer to the discharge time constant when S1 is closed, thereby removing the 20 volt source and shorting the source side of the lattice to ground.

So the key to solving this problem is to determine the discharge current path(s) for the cap.

When S2 is open, the upper 20 ohm and the right 10 ohm resistor are in series and this in turn is in parallel with the left 10 ohm resistor. This in turn is in series with the 2.5 ohm resistor. Solve this resistor lattice in that order and you can then calculate the time constant in that case.

When S2 is closed, this simply puts the 10 ohm resistor in parallel with the lattice value computed earlier before the addition of the 2.5 ohm series resistor. Recalculate the time constant with this new R <sub>lattice</sub> .

To calculate the capacitor discharge voltage at any time, you use the following formula:

V<sub>(t)</sub>=V<sub>0</sub>e<sup>-t/(RC)</sup>

Where V<sub>0</sub> is the initial voltage, t is the time in seconds, R is the discharge resistance in Ohms, and C is the capacitance in Farads. Note that you can use this formula to calculate the voltage starting from any point in the discharge curve.

You can calculate the capacitor charging voltage with the following formula:

V<sub>(t)</sub>=V<sub>S</sub>(1-e<sup>-t/(RC)</sup>)

Where V<sub>S</sub> is the supply voltage.

You may also observe that these two formulas are the basis for the more simple RC time constants of 63.2% for charging and 36.8% for discharging when -t/(RC)=-1.

Comment: ... where \$\small t\$ is essentially reset to zero at the instant the switches are operated, i.e. at \$\small t=30\mu s\$

Comment: True, but this exercise is theoretical to begin with.

Comment: Yes, but putting \$\small t=40 \mu s\$, for example, will not give the correct answer \$\small 10\mu s\$ after switching over.

Comment: @Glenn You are talking only about the discharging process. Doesn't the capacitor enter a charging fase when S1 is closed in A and a discharging fase when S1 is closed in B? In the problem it is said that Vc(0-)=0V where Vc(0-) is the capacitor voltage a moment before S1 is closed in A

Comment: @zethel I will add to my answer for the charge process description.

Comment: @chu Of course not. You have to put in the correct value for t. I will also be adding to my answer to describe the companion charging formula.

Comment: @Glenn can you help me with one last thing? I tried to find Vout(t) during the charging process but i got a strange result. Can you take a look and tell what did i do wrong? For t=0 i must have Vout(0)=0V(or not?) however from my formula i get 10V and it doesn't make sense to me.Here is how i did it: http://imgur.com/a/jJeBH . The Vc(t) is the capacitor voltage. I'm sorry for posting a link but it seems that i can't add an image in the comments.

Comment: @Glenn when you say "current as a funtion of time" you mean this: i(t)=Cdv/dt where dv/dt is the derivative of the capacitor voltage? If i use this then the current flowing through the series resistors will be a function of time as well. I must find it because i need the voltage for the right 10 ohm resistor (since the output voltage must be calculated between that resistor and the reference node). Is everything correct?

Comment: @Glenn I'm sorry but i don't understand why you say that Vout is the voltage from ground to the junction of the 7.5 ohm and 2.5 ohm resistors. This is what i understand from the circuit: http://imgur.com/a/m27i7 and this is what i understand from your answer: http://imgur.com/a/5y7eg. I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: @zethel Sorry, I was doing that from my phone. I will be back in the office shortly and will update my comments.

Comment: @zethel There are several ways to solve this. You can calculate the charging current through the capacitor as Ic=(Vs/R)*e(-t/RC). The total series resistance in the charging mode is 10 ohms. This will allow you to calculate the voltage drop across the 2.5 ohm resistor. The three resistor network that makes up the 7.5 ohms has the same current so the voltage drop across 7.5 ohms is easily calculated. The right 10 ohm resistor and the upper 20 ohm resistor form a simple voltage divider of that voltage.

Comment: @Glenn Okay, this method has the same solution i calculated before. Just like the last time i get Vout(0)=10V. The current is Ic=2e^(-t/RC). The voltage drop across the 7.5 ohm resistor is Vd=Ic*7.5=15e^(-t/RC). The voltage divider in the upper part of the circuit results in: V1=Vd*(10/(10+20))=Vd/3=5e^(-t/RC). Now, Vout=10 ohm resistor voltage+2.5 ohm resistor voltage+capacitor voltage=5e^(-t/RC)+5e^(-t/RC)+20(1-e^(-t/RC))=20-10e^(-t/RC). Vout(0)=10V

Comment: What are you using for t? At t=0, the capacitor is fully discharged.

Comment: t is the time. I want to know what is the value of Vout in t=0s

Comment: Yes, that is correct for t=0. Of course at that time the capacitor is a short circuit so the analysis could be "short circuited"! But it is always good to have a general form of the equation.

Comment: You won't believe me but i get 10V. Again. At least i know that the formula is working...

Comment: Good. It sounds like you have it then. I enjoyed the exchange. Have fun.

Comment: That's what i'm struggling with..Before S1 closes in A there is no current in the circuit so Vout should be zero. Why would it be 10V in t=0? The value should not jump from zero to 10 just like that. I'm really sorry, i know i'm making you lose a lot of time but i want to understand it.

Comment: In fact it does. If t=0 is the instant S1 closes (and S2 remains open and C was fully discharged) then the capacitor is effectively a short circuit. You can prove this yourself by setting t=0 in the capacitor charge formula. Since the capacitor is a short circuit, the resistor lattice forms the initial output voltage. But as the capacitor charges, the output voltage of the circuit will rise.

Comment: oh, so it starts from 10V, it will rise until a certain value(because the capacitor is charging) then S1 will get closed in B, S2 will get closed as well.The capacitor starts to discharge so the output voltage will decrease until zero if we leave it for some time.  http://imgur.com/a/YYWCV I will get something like this, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It would seem that you should compute the value of the output at t=30 us when charging according to the notes in the schematic. This will be the maximum voltage since at that time, S1 is opened and S2 is closed to initiate the discharge cycle.

Comment: @Glenn Thank you a lot for helping me out today. I mean it

Comment: @Zethel My pleasure.